# How to apply different select column name based on schema on dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have two different source of data with minor change in the schema and column name

e.g.

One input dataframe
`{ "id": "123", "customer_id": "xyz"... }`

another input dataframe
`{ "id": "345", "region": 1, "customerId": "abc" ...}`

In scala script, I need to have a mapper with selective columns from input and merge the required column to reduce in a single data frame

e.g.

```
val dataframe = input.map(row => row.select(
      col("id"),
      col("customer_id"))).reduce(_.union(_))

Where input is the Iterable[Dataset[Row]]
```

**The spark job is failing because of mismatch schema as**

```
InvalidScalaScriptException.message: {"message":"No such struct field customer_id
```

Is there any way to be schema aware and pick the columns being indifferent to the position or minor name change on column name ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it pretty much depends on how you want to measure similarity. For instance, I can say that if column name contains all the characters of "customerid", the columns are the same, so I can propose you this approach:

```scala
def getSimilarColumnName(allColumnsOfDF: Seq[String], expectedChars: String): String = { // although I believe Option[String] is safer
  allColumnsOfDF.collectFirst {
    case column if expectedChars.forall(c => column.toLowerCase.contains(c.toChar)) => 
      column
  }.getOrElse("SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE_OR_EXCEPTION__SOMEHOW_MANAGE_IT")
}
```

And given the similarity function:

```scala
input.map { dataframe =>
  dataframe.select(
    dataframe.col("id"),
    dataframe.col(getSimilarColumnName(dataframe.columns, "customerid"))
  )
}.reduce(_.union(_))
```